# How to make a script with IF work separately in more than one row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

The script bellow works perfectly for the `row` in `C5`. However, I need it to work for the rows below it, separately. An `IF` check for each row, let's say.

Any thoughts on how to do that?

I tried changing the `Range` to, for instance, `"C5:C10"` and `G5:Q10`, respectively, but it didn't work.

```
function ClearOKs() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange("C5").getValue();
  
  if(workingCell === ""){
    activeSheet.getRange("G5:Q5").createTextFinder("OK").replaceAllWith("")
  }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what the script should do and explain what you mean by "it didn't work". If your script is throwing an error, please add it textually.

Answer (score 1):

You want to run a script on a single cell, or a range of cells.

Use `getCurrentCell()` or `getActiveRange()` to define the rows(s)/column(s) in `getRange`. This would enable you to select a range and then execute the script on that range.

---

**Current Cell**

```
function theCurrentCell() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  var cellRow = currentCell.getRow();
  var cellCol = currentCell.getColumn();
  Logger.log("the current cell is "+currentCell.getA1Notation()+", row = "+cellRow+", column = "+cellCol);
}
```

---

**Active Range**

```
function theActiveRange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currentRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var cellRow = currentRange.getRowIndex();
  var cellNumrows = currentRange.getNumRows();
  var cellCol = currentRange.getColumn();
  var cellNumcol = currentRange.getNumColumns();
  Logger.log("the current range is "+currentRange.getA1Notation()+", row = "+cellRow+", number of rows = "+cellNumrows+", col = "+cellCol+", num of columns = "+cellNumcol);
}
```